# Table tests with errors

Tags: go

given a Golang function like this:

```
func GetKey(key string, data map[string]string) (string, error) {
    value, present := data[key]

    if !present {
        return "", errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("requested key does not exist: %s", key))
    }

    return value, nil
}
```

how would i go about testing the presence of the error I return, using Test Tables?  For example:

```
func TestGetKey(t *testing.T) {

    cases := []struct {
        Input  map[string]string
        Key    string
        Result string
        Err    error
    }{
        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "foo",
            "bar",
            nil,
        },

        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "nope",
            "",
            ????,
        },
    }

    // and something like
    for _, v := range cases {
        actual, err := GetKey(v.Key, v.Input)
        if actual != v.Result {
            t.Fatalf("Expected %s. Got %s", v.Result, actual)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Get` func should use `fmt.Errorf(...)` instead of `errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(...))`.

Comment: It would be also safer to report using `%q` instead of `%s` for better readability of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not seeing something, but this is usually how I do it:

```
actual, err := GetKey(v.Key)
if err != v.Err {
    t.Errorf("Unexpected error: %s", err)
}
```

Or, if the returned error might not be a specific known error value, I might flatten to a string:

```
actual, err := GetKey(v.Key)
var errMsg string
if err != nil {
    errMsg = err.Error()
}
if errMsg != v.errMsg {
    t.Errorf("Unexpected error: %s", errMsg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the same error you are expecting to get and then assert that both return the same `Error()`.

So in your map, for the error case:

```
{
   map[string]string{
       "foo": "bar",
       "baz": "bah",
   },
   "nope",
   "",
   errors.New("requested key does not exist: nope"),
}
```

And in your test code:

```
for _, v := range cases {
    actual, err := GetKey(v.Key, v.Input)
    if actual != v.Result {
        t.Fatalf("Expected %s. Got %s", v.Result, actual)
    }
    if (v.Err != nil) && (err == nil) {
        t.Fatalf("Expecting error (%s), did not get it", v.Err.Error())
    } else if (v.Err == nil) && (err != nil) {
        t.Fatalf("Got unexpected error: (%s)", err.Error())
    } else if (v.Err != nil) && (err != nil) && (v.Err.Error() != err.Error()) {
        t.Fatalf("Expecting error (%s). Got (%s)", v.Err.Error(), err.Error())
    }
}
```

Note that there are several cases for when you don't expected an error but actually got one, expected one and did not get it, and expected one and got a different one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't get the exact `error` value for comparison, you must fallback to comparing the error message: `err.Error()`.

So change the table test to expect a string in the table ([run](https://go.dev/play/p/M4pzb_oSDyN) on the Go Playground):

```
func TestGetKey(t *testing.T) {

    cases := []struct {
        Input  map[string]string
        Key    string
        Result string
        Err    string // <-- CHANGE
    }{
        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "", // <-- CHANGE
        },

        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "nope",
            "",
            "requested key does not exist: nope", // <-- CHANGE
        },
    }

    // and something like
    for _, v := range cases {
        actual, err := GetKey(v.Key, v.Input)
        if v.Err == "" { // <-- ADDED BLOCK
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("Unexpected error %q", err)
            }
        } else if got := err.Error(); got != v.Err {
            t.Fatalf("Got error %q, expected %q", got, v.Err)
        }
        if actual != v.Result {
            t.Fatalf("Expected %s. Got %s", v.Result, actual)
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to define a custom `error` type that would make the key name directly accessible. Also, testing the spelling of the error message is not that important: what matters is that an error is reported and that the key is mentionned.

See the code running on the Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/2s1PvVpcd23

```
type KeyNotFoundError string

func (e KeyNotFoundError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("key does not exist: %q", string(e))
}

func GetKey(key string, data map[string]string) (string, error) {
    value, present := data[key]

    if !present {
        return "", KeyNotFoundError(key)
    }

    return value, nil
}

func TestGetKey(t *testing.T) {

    cases := []struct {
        Input  map[string]string
        Key    string
        Result string
        Err    error
    }{
        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "foo",
            "bar",
            nil,
        },

        {
            map[string]string{
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bah",
            },
            "nope",
            "",
            KeyNotFoundError("nope"), // <-- CHANGE HERE
        },
    }

    // and something like
    for _, v := range cases {
        actual, err := GetKey(v.Key, v.Input)
        if v.Err == nil { // <-- ADDED BLOCK
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("Unexpected error %q", err)
            }
        } else if got := err; reflect.TypeOf(got) != reflect.TypeOf(v.Err) || got.Error() != v.Err.Error() {
            t.Fatalf("Got error %T %[1]q, expected %T %[2]q", got, v.Err)
        }
        if actual != v.Result {
            t.Fatalf("Expected %s. Got %s", v.Result, actual)
        }
    }
}
```